# Nginx no redirecciona todo el tráfico http

Tags: nginx, docker

Configuré https con letsencrypt en nginx, y accediendo por ip en la mayoría de casos si redirecciona a https, pero si entro específicamente por esta ruta `http://11.255.123.0:4040/login`
accede sin cifrar, alguna sugerencia? Dejo aquí la configuración de nginx:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
```

}

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4040/;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
 }
```

Estuve investigando más y todas las que tienen que ver con las imágenes de docker activas están sin redirección /parse :1337 y :4040

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El puerto 4040 no lo está atendiendo nginx, sino que es el puerto en el que el app server está corriendo.

Lo que deberías hacer es que el firewall limite todos los requests al 4040 excepto en la interfaz de loopback (127.0.0.1)